# Woocommerce Force category choice before creating new product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I force the user to first choose a category product before continuing to the editor when creating a new product?

I found a successful solution but it is working for posts not products.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/force-category-choice-before-creating-new-post

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the code your refer will work for you if you change the following code :

```
  $post_type = 'post';
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
        $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
    }

    // Only do this for posts
    if ( 'post' != $post_type ) {
        return;
    }
```

To

```
$post_type = 'product';
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
    $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
}

// Only do this for posts
if ( 'product' != $post_type ) {
    return;
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried it, when I click "add product", I get the page to force me to choose a category, but it list the posts categories not products categories.